# SQL Server 2012 Create unique index with constraint on table creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using database projects in Visual Studio and I'm looking to make a unique index with a where clause on table creation, rather than having to create the table and add another script to add the constraint to the index.  My constraint is

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_IdNotNull
ON MyTable(MyId)
WHERE MyId IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm looking for something like

```
create table MyTable
(
    MyId int unique where MyId is not null
)
```

but SSMS doesn't like this.  Is it possible to assign a where clause to a unique constraint when the table is created?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012, no. In later versions, yes. SQL Server 2017, at least, accepts `CREATE TABLE MyTable(MyId INT NULL, INDEX ix_IdNotNull UNIQUE(MyId) WHERE MyId IS NOT NULL)`. For 2012, I think having the `CREATE INDEX` separately is unavoidable (and note that it *is* an index, and not a constraint -- `UNIQUE` constraints cannot be filtered).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was afraid that was the case.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: There's not much you lose -- creating an index on an empty table is instantaneous, and you *can* wrap both `CREATE`s in a transaction if you had a reason to worry about the very small moment in time where the table existed without its index.

Comment: If I wasn't using a database project in VS ,then I wouldn't worry about it at all, and I suppose as long as I add the couple lines to create it at the bottom of the script where the table lives, it's not a big deal.  But IME, database projects start to get wonky when you do uncommon things in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add NC UNIQUE index

For sql 2016 +

```
create table MyTable
(
    MyId int ,

    INDEX [i_MyTable] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (MyId) WHERE [MyId] IS NOT NULL
)
```

early version

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i_MyTable]
ON [MyTable] (MyId)
WHERE [MyId] IS NOT NULL
```